# CSS3 - How do I create a circular border-radius on a rectangle?

Tags: html, css

I have a div. It scales responsively, using percentages. I would like to have the edges be circular.

I know how to make rounded corners. I would like to make it shaped like this (don't care about color).
[image: this rounded corner]
I'd really like to avoid JavaScript if possible, but if it is the only way, so be it.

Comment: If you know how to make rounded corners what issues are you having? Where's your code?

Comment: use `border-radius: 100%`

Comment: @AbdulAhmad Thanks, but NTL already answered my question. That would make an oval, sadly.

Comment: @j08691 what I meant was that I can make a rounded rectangle, I wasn't sure how to make a rounded rectangle that had completely round sides without distorting the corners.

Comment: That's fine, however you always should post an example of the code you're working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `border-radius: 50px` property to the css.

Comment: Huh. That worked, surprisingly. I thought it would make an oval corner because my object is smaller that 50px;